# How to change kernel message VT in linux

Tags: terminal, linux-kernel, dmesg

I feel kinda stupid, since I'm certain I used to know this. But here goes.

How can I change which VT kernel messages print to? I use text-mode primarily, typically on vt1. Unfortunately, kernel messages also print to vt1. I don't want to *disable* the kernel messages, just... relocate them to another terminal. How can I set it so that Kernel messages print to, say, vt7?

Thanks!

Comment: just add console=tty6 to kernel boot options should be ok.

Comment: @Mali, it seems that it just changes which tty is presented for login, so console=tty6 just means that I'll be using tty6 by default. I actually want to dump messages to tty6, and still have tty1 as my default.